# Image upload using UploadFileInterface

Tags: php

This is the function to verify if the extension of a file is acceptable.
When i run it shows an error.Help me please.

Error shows Call to a member function getError() on string

```
public function extension(string $key, array $extensions): self
{
    /** @var UploadedFileInterface $file */
    $file = $this->getValue($key);
    if ($file !== null && $file->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $type = $file->getClientMediaType();
        $extension = mb_strtolower(pathinfo($file->getClientFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        $expectedType = self::MIME_TYPES[$extension] ?? null;
        if (!in_array($extension, $extensions) || $expectedType !== $type) {
            $this->addError($key, 'filetype', [join(',', $extensions)]);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Looks like `$file` is a string not an instance of `UploadedFile`

Comment: i add that on the php doc. when am writting it auto complete the rest since its an instance of the interface.

Comment: i solved the problem

Comment: Can you explan how? It might be useful for others facing same problem in future.

Comment: Completely forgot to add the attribute "multipart/form-data" on the form tag to precise I was going to post a file.